# How to make Debian prompt before restarting services after package upgrades?

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have VPS instances from three different providers, and those from two providers will prompt for a restart of affected services when running `apt-get upgrade`.

VPS instances from one provider do NOT prompt during the upgrade, which then requires me to go and restart services afterwards manually.

I've seen mention of this setting elsewhere, but it doesn't seem to be present on any of my systems:

```
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

I don't know if it is relevant, but all of these VPS instances originally had Debian 7 and were upgraded a couple months ago to Debian 8. Prior to that, I don't remember ANY of them prompting to restart services, so I suspect this behavior is new to Debian 8.

So how do I get ALL of my systems to prompt me for restarting services during an upgrade? Bonus: is there a way to tell apt-get to always restart services without even prompting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `needrestart` package will implement what you are describing once installed.

Comment: @nosilver4u needrestart (https://packages.debian.org/needrestart) supports both, kernel checks (you need a reboot because the on disk kernel is newer than the booted on) and library checks (you need to restart daemon foo because it uses an old version of library bar that was just upgraded). I understood that the later is what you asked for, no?

Answer (score 0):

The prompt is because the services that those libraries depend of have special checks to make them restart as earlier as possible, for example glibc has a handful of [critical services that must be restarted as earlier as possible](https://salsa.debian.org/glibc-team/glibc/blob/aaa2e753affb7ddb493ab0978f026b8ddbeecc6d/debian/debhelper.in/libc.postinst#L32). If those systems aren't running these services or they don't have a interactive session opened when those libraries upgrade they will not prompt for a restart, they either don't need to or is being upgraded in an interactive session and henceforth it asks you.

To get a prompt before upgrading you have to:

- have services that need to be restarted, because
- libraries are critical and services should be restarted as soon as possible, and
- have an interactive session

If one of the three are not present you will not get prompted.

Comment: Turns out it was the `needrestart` package as @zhenech thought. I totally understand the "why" of services needing a restart, but that IS good information for anyone else that might be curious. In my case, all three of the conditions you mentioned were true, but some systems were still not prompting to restart services as they should have been.